# Configure source maps for extract-text-webpack-plugin

Tags: webpack, source-maps, extract-text-plugin

How can I configure extract-text-webpack-plugin to generate source maps when *devtools* config option is set to any value containing "source-map" (not only exact match)?

Answer (score 2):

You should do vice versa.
Something like this will definitely work. Just configure with SCSS/LESS if required.

```
var DEBUG_MODE = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

module.exports = {
   ...
   devtool: DEBUG_MODE ? 'cheap-source-map' : 'source-map'
   ...
   module: {
          loaders: [
            { 
              test: /\.css$/, 
              loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-loader") 
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css")
    ]
```

Comment: Thanks! But this not exactly what I'm trying to achieve: I'd like ExtractTextPlugin to generate source maps both for dev and for prod. For dev we have 'devtool' set to 'cheap-source-map' and for prod it is set to 'source-map'. So when I'm running dev configuration the CSS source maps are empty.

Comment: @kirschpirogge : I have updated the solution for your req.
   devtool: DEBUG_MODE ? 'cheap-source-map' : 'source-map'

Comment: Ok, cool! But when 'devtool' is set to 'cheap-source-map' then ExtractTextPlugin doesn't generate source maps for CSS. Can it be configured somehow to generate them?

Comment: @kirschpirogge : If you want a separate file, then use source-map.
You can refer here for in further details : http://cheng.logdown.com/posts/2016/03/25/679045

Also, if the above answer helped you, then just mark that as Accepted/Upvote.

Comment: Downvoted because as mentioned in this [official docs](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin), ExtractTextPlugin only works with devtool: "source-map" setting.